# Colocar uma condição no order by mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, sqlite

Estou com dúvidas sobre um assunto referente a order by. Na minha tabela tem as seguintes informações:

```
ID | ORDEM | NOME
1  |  0    | NOME01
2  |  2    | NOME02
3  |  1    | NOME03
```

Quero dar um select onde primeiro vai ordenar pela coluna ORDEM, depois pela coluna ID, porém se na coluna ORDEM estiver com 0 então ele vai ficar por ultimo Como exemplo abaixo:

```
ID | ORDEM | NOME
3  | 1     | NOME03
2  | 2     | NOME02
1  | 0     | NOME01
```

O codigo que eu pensei até agora foi

```
SELECT ID, ORDEM, NOME FROM agenda ORDER BY ordem ASC, ID ASC
```

mas aparece o que está em ordem 0 por primeiro.
Como posso ver isto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu consegui entender o que você quis dizer seria isso,utilizar o case se for 0 ordena decrescente senão ascendente

```
 SELECT ID, ORDEM, NOME 
    FROM agenda
     ORDER BY   (case when ordem = 0 then ordem end) desc,
                 (case when ordem <> 0 then ordem end), ID ASC;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Não tem de quê, fico feliz em poder ajudar